# Ionic - Push Notifications between two different Apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic project developing two different Apps:

1) The Companies App - Companies will be able to post new job opportunities.

2) The users App - They will be able to check for any role, if an user applies for a role, the Company that is offering the job, should receive a Push Notification.

As you can see, my problem is: how an App will Push to the other one ? Does Ionic have a solution for that? If not, there is another way to solve this?

Looking forward to hear from you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of push notifications is to give backend servers the ability to initiate communication and notify mobile devices with updates. This said, You have to do server side logic to achieve what you need, here is a sample scenario for your case:

1. Register your companies app to ionic.io, following the steps on [ionic push quick start guide](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-quick-start), when you register your app gets a unique ID that you can use from your server side code to send push notifications, sample code for python can be found in [API Examples](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-api-examples)
2. Company A uses the companies app to post a new job that will be added in a database on your server. Company A can choose to subsbribe to push notifications, when they do, a unique token ID will be generated for this device, send this token to your backend server because you will need it to send the notification, check [API Examples](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-api-examples)
3. User B uses the users app to apply for the job, his application is
   propagated to the server.
4. Your server side code will determine that this job was posted by company A which is subscribed to push notifications, and will use the company token id, [the application id, and the application secret](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/io-api-keys) key to send a notifications to the company on the companies app.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I like this approach and that's all I need. How can I achieve this ? Do you know ?

Comment: Do you have any kind of backend for your application?

Comment: Yes, I do, python / django. What I dont know is how to identify each device to Push...

Comment: I just edited my answer to include the info you needed on how to identify the device and how to send the notifications.